# Load views from different assemblies Using VirtualPathProvider

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, virtualpathprovider

I use this code to load views from embedded resources. My main purpose is to load  from different assemblies too.
Sorry if it's duplicate but I couldn't find my answer.

```
using SecondApp.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace PathProviderSample
{
public class EmbeddedVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    public EmbeddedVirtualFile(string virtualPath)
        : base(virtualPath)
    {
    }

    internal static string GetResourceName(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (!virtualPath.Contains("/Views/"))
        {
            return null;
        }


        var resourcename = virtualPath
            .Substring(virtualPath.IndexOf("Views/"))
            .Replace("Views/", "SecondApp.Views.")
            .Replace("/", ".");

        return resourcename;

    }


    public override Stream Open()
    {
        Assembly assembly = typeof(TestController).Assembly;


        var resourcename = GetResourceName(this.VirtualPath);
        return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcename);
    }




}

public class Vpp : VirtualPathProvider
{


    private bool ResourceFileExists(string virtualPath)
    {

        Assembly assembly = typeof(TestController).Assembly;


        var resourcename = EmbeddedVirtualFile.GetResourceName(virtualPath);
        var result = resourcename != null && assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Contains(resourcename);
        return result;
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        return base.FileExists(virtualPath) || ResourceFileExists(virtualPath);
    }


    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {

        if (!base.FileExists(virtualPath))
        {
            return new EmbeddedVirtualFile(virtualPath);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }

    }
}
```

}

It loads views from its own assembly but when I request a view from other project (other dll) it cannot find the view .

embedded in main dll : http://localhost:49892/Home/Index2   // it works
embedded in other dll : http://localhost:49892/Test/Index   // cannot find

Comment: Is that the exact error message "cannot find the view" ?

Comment: @jeremy-thompson Server Error in '/' Application.
Directory 'c:\users\administrator.unospc\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PathProviderSample\PathProviderSample\Views\Test' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.

Comment: Actually It wants to load the view from main assembly . but the view is in other one